# What specific PPA does Unity come from?

Tags: 12.04, unity, server

So me and another where looking around and just couldn't find this item.  We are wanting a Minimal Ubuntu Server install with Unity. Problem is, there is no simple way to pick out a single PPA to which Unity is connected to.  Originally, no source PPAs are listed.  How does one find this info and what Terminal commands would be used to download and install just that?

Comment: Assuming you're talking about Unity the shell, why would you need a PPA?

Comment: @karel Unfortunately the dependencies for `ubuntu-desktop` are not in the repositories (this is for 12.04, not 14.04)

Comment: @NoTime Any specific dependency? Or do you mean something is not available in `main`?

Comment: ubuntu-desktop is a package in the Ubuntu 12.04 repos and so are its dependencies. By that I mean ubuntu-desktop and all of its dependencies are in the repos for both Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @muru It's reading off a bunch of dependencies that cannot be installed atm. Went through and uncommented stuff in sources, and did `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `update`. It appears that the old repos are.. well old, not sure if I would have to get a new sources list. The iso (running in virtual box) is from older versions area.

Comment: If `ubuntu-desktop` is not installable for you on 12.04, then there is a problem with the packages already installed on your system, or your packaging information is not up to date.

Comment: @dobey it is fresh install in virtualbox (2nd time) no other packages are installed

Comment: If you guys want to jump in chat.. (general) so this doesn't become 30 comments running down

Comment: @NoTime I second dobey. What is your `sources.list` atm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Steps taken to get correct items in repositories** (with a lot of help from Muru)

1. Edit DNS: `sudo nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base`

   - put `nameserver 8.8.8.8` (Sets to Google DNS, I was receiving hostname errors when trying to do update prior)
   - `resolvconf -u` (Resolves Name Conflict)
2. Edit software sources

   - `sed -i.bak 's/us.archive/ca.archive/' /etc/apt/sources.list` (Search for 'us', replace with 'ca')
   - If that doesn't work, edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and replace 'us' with 'ca'
   - I also uncommented all, but this shouldn't be necessary
3. Update from new sources: `sudo apt-get update`

Note: Still was getting a GPG error with the `extras`, saying No Public Key.

I am able to install OpenBox, and other window managers now, instead of full `ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: Could you explain why changing your DNS is a necessary step?

Comment: @amanthethy tried to add more on why I needed to do DNS

Comment: Could the same not be achieved with `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends unity/openbox/i3/gnoome/kde/etc.`? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @amanthethy there was a problem with the sources (fresh install on vm) where nothing could be grabbed from the repositories (almost nothing was downloading). What I was trying to do was to get a minimum GUI to work with Ubuntu without ubuntu-desktop, but things like `xserver` were not in repository.

Comment: That's really strange! After getting your DNS issues resolved, did an apt-get update reveal these 'missing' packages as actually present and installable? Or are they still not available?

Comment: If you want to see the director's cut, the whole discussion was in the Ask Ubuntu General Room chat about a half hour ago.

Comment: @amanthethy I had to change my source list from us to ca, after changing DNS. I still get a GPG error for extras (because it is not a us.extras or ca.extras) at this moment it is ok, because I can add it later.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a minimal Ubuntu with Unity, a PPA doesn't [necessarily] give you what you want.

Unity is just a package. Available from the main repos. You can take a minimal `ubuntu-standard` Server install and `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends unity` and it'll install *everything* Unity needs to run. You can see a list from `apt-rdepends unity` (included below to highlight the magnitude). My point is **using a Unity PPA won't lower the number of  dependencies**.

And a quick sidebar, if you are shooting for the smallest Unity-based system, you might need a few more X11 packages and you'll also need to install a desktop manager (like LightDM) or hack something in as I have in [my kiosk computing tutorial](https://thepcspy.com/read/building-a-kiosk-computer-ubuntu-1404-chrome/).

`adduser`, `bamfdaemon`, `base-passwd`, `busybox-initramfs`, `compiz`, `compiz-core`, `compiz-core-abiversion-20140123`, `compiz-gnome`, `compiz-plugins-default`, `coreutils`, `cpio`, `dbus`, `dbus-x11`, `dconf-cli`, `dconf-gsettings-backend`, `dconf-service`, `debconf`, `debconf-2.0`, `debianutils`, `dh-python`, `dpkg`, `file-rc`, `findutils`, `fontconfig`, `fontconfig-config`, `fonts-dejavu-core`, `fonts-freefont-ttf`, `gcc-4.8-base`, `gcc-4.9-base`, `gconf2`, `gconf2-common`, `gconf-service`, `gconf-service-backend`, `glib-networking`, `glib-networking-common`, `glib-networking-services`, `gnome-desktop3-data`, `gnome-icon-theme`, `gnome-icon-theme-full`, `gnome-settings-daemon-schemas`, `gsettings-backend`, `gsettings-desktop-schemas`, `gsfonts`, `gsfonts-x11`, `hicolor-icon-theme`, `humanity-icon-theme`, `ifupdown`, `initramfs-tools`, `initramfs-tools-bin`, `initscripts`, `insserv`, `install-info`, `iproute2`, `klibc-utils`, `kmod`, `libacl1`, `libapparmor1`, `libasn1-8-heimdal`, `libasound2`, `libasound2-data`, `libatk1.0-0`, `libatk1.0-data`, `libatk-bridge2.0-0`, `libatspi2.0-0`, `libattr1`, `libaudit1`, `libaudit-common`, `libavahi-client3`, `libavahi-common3`, `libavahi-common-data`, `libbamf3-2`, `libblkid1`, `libbz2-1.0`, `libc6`, `libcairo2`, `libcairo-gobject2`, `libcanberra0`, `libcgmanager0`, `libcolord1`, `libcomerr2`, `libcompizconfig0`, `libcroco3`, `libcups2`, `libdatrie1`, `libdb5.3`, `libdbus-1-3`, `libdbus-glib-1-2`, `libdbusmenu-glib4`, `libdconf1`, `libdebconfclient0`, `libdecoration0`, `libdee-1.0-4`, `libdrm2`, `libelfg0`, `libexpat1`, `libffi6`, `libfontconfig1`, `libfontenc1`, `libframe6`, `libfreetype6`, `libgcc1`, `libgconf-2-4`, `libgcrypt11`, `libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0`, `libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common`, `libgee2`, `libgeis1`, `libgl1`, `libgl1-mesa-glx`, `libglapi-mesa`, `libglew1.10`, `libglewmx1.10`, `libglib2.0-0`, `libglib2.0-bin`, `libglib2.0-data`, `libglibmm-2.4-1c2a`, `libglu1`, `libglu1-mesa`, `libgnome-desktop-3-7`, `libgnutls26`, `libgpg-error0`, `libgrail6`, `libgraphite2-3`, `libgssapi3-heimdal`, `libgssapi-krb5-2`, `libgtk2.0-0`, `libgtk2.0-common`, `libgtk-3-0`, `libgtk-3-bin`, `libgtk-3-common`, `libgtop2-7`, `libgtop2-common`, `libharfbuzz0b`, `libhcrypto4-heimdal`, `libheimbase1-heimdal`, `libheimntlm0-heimdal`, `libhx509-5-heimdal`, `libibus-1.0-5`, `libice6`, `libicu52`, `libido3-0.1-0`, `libindicator3-7`, `libjasper1`, `libjbig0`, `libjpeg8`, `libjpeg-turbo8`, `libjson0`, `libjson-c2`, `libjson-glib-1.0-0`, `libjson-glib-1.0-common`, `libk5crypto3`, `libkeyutils1`, `libklibc`, `libkmod2`, `libkrb5-26-heimdal`, `libkrb5-3`, `libkrb5support0`, `liblcms2-2`, `libldap-2.4-2`, `liblightdm-gobject-1-0`, `libltdl7`, `liblzma5`, `libmetacity-private0a`, `libmount1`, `libmpdec2`, `libncurses5`, `libncursesw5`, `libnih1`, `libnih-dbus1`, `libnotify4`, `libnux-4.0-0`, `libnux-4.0-common`, `libnux-abiversion-20140307.0`, `libogg0`, `libp11-kit0`, `libpam0g`, `libpam-modules`, `libpam-modules-bin`, `libpango-1.0-0`, `libpangocairo-1.0-0`, `libpangoft2-1.0-0`, `libpci3`, `libpcre3`, `libpixman-1-0`, `libplymouth2`, `libpng12-0`, `libprocps3`, `libprotobuf8`, `libproxy1`, `libpython3.4-minimal`, `libpython3.4-stdlib`, `libpython3-stdlib`, `libreadline6`, `libroken18-heimdal`, `librsvg2-2`, `librsvg2-common`, `libsasl2-2`, `libsasl2-modules-db`, `libselinux1`, `libsemanage1`, `libsemanage-common`, `libsepol1`, `libsigc++-2.0-0c2a`, `libslang2`, `libsm6`, `libsoup2.4-1`, `libsoup-gnome2.4-1`, `libsqlite3-0`, `libssl1.0.0`, `libstartup-notification0`, `libstdc++6`, `libsystemd-login0`, `libtasn1-6`, `libtdb1`, `libthai0`, `libthai-data`, `libtiff5`, `libtinfo5`, `libudev0`, `libudev1`, `libunity9`, `libunity-core-6.0-9`, `libunity-misc4`, `libunity-protocol-private0`, `libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop`, `libupstart1`, `libustr-1.0-1`, `libuuid1`, `libvorbis0a`, `libvorbisfile3`, `libwayland-client0`, `libwayland-cursor0`, `libwind0-heimdal`, `libwnck22`, `libwnck-3-0`, `libwnck-3-common`, `libwnck-common`, `libx11-6`, `libx11-data`, `libx11-xcb1`, `libxau6`, `libxaw7`, `libxcb1`, `libxcb-dri2-0`, `libxcb-dri3-0`, `libxcb-glx0`, `libxcb-present0`, `libxcb-render0`, `libxcb-shm0`, `libxcb-sync1`, `libxcb-util0`, `libxcomposite1`, `libxcursor1`, `libxdamage1`, `libxdmcp6`, `libxext6`, `libxfixes3`, `libxfont1`, `libxi6`, `libxinerama1`, `libxkbcommon0`, `libxkbfile1`, `libxklavier16`, `libxml2`, `libxmu6`, `libxpm4`, `libxrandr2`, `libxrender1`, `libxres1`, `libxshmfence1`, `libxt6`, `libxxf86vm1`, `libzeitgeist-2.0-0`, `lsb-base`, `lsb-release`, `makedev`, `metacity-common`, `mime-support`, `module-init-tools`, `mount`, `mountall`, `multiarch-support`, `netbase`, `nux-tools`, `passwd`, `perl-base`, `plymouth`, `procps`, `psmisc`, `python3`, `python3.4`, `python3.4-minimal`, `python3:any`, `python3-minimal`, `python:any`, `readline-common`, `sensible-utils`, `session-migration`, `sgml-base`, `shared-mime-info`, `sound-theme-freedesktop`, `sysvinit-utils`, `sysv-rc`, `tar`, `ttf-bitstream-vera`, `tzdata`, `ucf`, `udev`, `unity`, `unity-asset-pool`, `unity-greeter`, `unity-scope-home`, `unity-scopes-json-def`, `unity-scopes-master`, `unity-scopes-master-default`, `unity-services`, `upstart`, `util-linux`, `x11-common`, `x11-xkb-utils`, `xfonts-encodings`, `xfonts-utils`, `xkb-data`, `zlib1g`.

Comment: I read your kiosk article before, it was really cool how you set things up. After tweaking my server a bit in VM I have an ubuntu server (with no extra services) openbox, no unity or any ubuntu-desktop and terminator. Otherwise it is pretty sparse. I was having issues initially getting **anything** from repos. I might do a lite unity as well for fun. :)

Answer (score 1):

PPA is a "Personal Package Archive" - they are mini-repositories, so users can offer packages.

The unity shell is integral part of the Ubuntu distribution and in the main repository.
The "unity" package installs the Unity shell binary, and all the dependencies it needs.

With `apt-cache show unity` you can get some infos about the package. Not sure if installing it will suffice though. There is also `ubuntu-desktop` which is a meta-package for a desktop system, but that might be too much.

Comment: `unity` is not a meta-package, since it does provide the `unity` binary, along with a few other files.

Comment: I can do apt-cache show unity (cannot install, reads off a bunch of dependencies which cannot be installed). `ubuntu-desktop` is the same

Comment: I don't understand your comment. So you CAN see the information? What is the problem? You can't install it? What is the error?
But please note, that you are hijacking a thread here. We don't answer secondary questions in comments on StackExchange. Open up a question if it is a new one, or if you have the same issue as OP provide more info.

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer Question reads "So me and another where". Presumably NoTime is the "another".